# What Is The Meaning 'I'm Not', is a lie

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence

What is the meaning of these two sentences:

> The truth is, the belief 'I'm Not', is a lie.
>
> Before we ever agree to believe I'm Not, it was someone else's
>   opinion.

I tried my best but still need to understand them properly in their real context.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You talk about understanding them in their real context. So tell us what the real context is. Where did these sentences come from? Did you write them? Did you read them? If so where? Do you have a link? The first sounds like pseudo-philosophy, the second sounds like ungrammatical nonsense.

Comment: It's generic positive-thinking self-actualizing fluff. It means "I can be whatever I want to be"; "I shouldn't listen to the voice that tells me I'm not good enough"; "All criticisms start externally, i.e. with other people telling me what I can and cannot be". Whether you want to buy into that philosophy ... well, it's your book.

Comment: *I'm Not* able to fly by flapping my arms.  Just someone else's opinion.

Comment: It's meaningless prattle from some wannabe philosopher.

Answer (score 2):

To me (native English speaker), the speaker seems to mean that our negative beliefs about ourselves have their origin in somebody else's opinion of us. Put another way, it means that we are open to believing ourselves capable of anything or as part of any group until someone tells us otherwise.

In this reading, the phrase 'I'm not' would be shorthand for a category of phrases, such as 'I'm not a writer' or 'I'm not good at math' or 'I'm not able to succeed'.

It is a bit awkwardly put, and sounds like part of a self-help or inspirational spiel.